# How do I add a program that must be run from within its own directory to the panel or main menu?

Tags: gnome, panel, scripts, menu

Some programs can only be run from within their own directories. If I go to `System --> Preferences --> Main Menu --> Add Item` and select the file, it will not work. Similarly, if I right click on the Panel and choose "Add to Panel...", choose "Custom Application Launcher," and then point to the file, it will similarly fail. How can I add a launcher to my panel and an entry in my Main Menu that will successfully launch this kind of program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I did is this:

I created a plain text file and wrote the following bash script for a Latin translation program I use, called [Words](http://archives.nd.edu/whitaker/words.htm):

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~/latin/latin.words/

./words
```

After saving it in my home folder, I made it executable, which can be done in one of two ways.  I right clicked on it, choose **Properties->Permissions**, and check the **"Execute"** box for your user name.  Or I could have used the command line and entered `chmod +x file.name` .

Then I right clicked on the panel and chose **Add to Panel**, select **Custom Application Launcher.** I entered the name, in this case **Words**, and the path to the script I just wrote in the **Command** field.  Because `Words` is a command line program, I selected **Program in Terminal** from the drop-down menu. I then clicked on the icon and selected an appropriate one and with that I was done adding it to the panel.

Next I clicked **System->Preferences->Main** Menu, selected the folder I wanted to put the menu launcher into, and then clicked **Add Item.**  I then repeated the process I just performed, above.

And now I have a custom launcher that works for a program that must be run from its own directory, both on my panel and in the menu!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using a script to launch the app instead?

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/dir
myprogram
```

Select the script instead of the file.

Answer (score 2):

`cd /path/to/dir/ && gksudo bin_file`

That should do the trick.